# Is there any way to fixed css height of alert-sucess class of bootsrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The main page of an html and css learning project has 3 columns using the bootstrap 3 classes. The first contains a text and a button to copy this text to the clipboard. The second and third have a link.

I tried to configure with the codes below.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/buhvm3o8/4/

html code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div id="select_txt" class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>some text do copy</strong>

        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" onclick="copy_data(select_txt)" style="float: right;">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></i>copy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#">site1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#">site2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```css
body {
  font-family: "roboto", monospace;
  height: 100%;
}

.alert-success {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

My questions are:

1. How can I set the "col-md-4" correctly so that it is as a column, because as shown in the image below, it is as a row.

[image: now]

2. How can I set the "col-md-4" to the screen height of anyone looking at it.

[image: expected]

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Bootstrap's [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) to ensure that your columns are always the proper width. Right now they are set to be 12 units long when the screen size is below medium, and 4 units long at any greater size. Instead, you should have col-xs-4 on you class to force it to be 4 units at *every* screen size.
2. The easiest method would be to use the `vh` unit in CSS. Add a class to the column in question and set the height to `height: 100vh` which corresponds to 100% of the view height.

Other methods include using Flexbox to force the page width, or the
    always troublesome 100%
    height attribute. In most cases, in order for 100% height to work, you will
    need either (a) [all parents of the element to have their height set
    to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464208/3338349) or (b) the [direct parent to have a statically defined height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin)

[Your fiddle with the updated values and the 100% height method](https://jsfiddle.net/Renson/mL96no5h/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding xs breakpoint for smaller screens:

```css
body {
  font-family: "roboto", monospace;
  height: 100%;
}

.alert-success {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div id="select_txt" class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>some text to copy</strong>

        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button" onclick="copy_data(select_txt)" style="float: right;">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></i>copy</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#">site1</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#">site2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. That's the expected behavior of columns in Bootstrap! They collapse when the device's width get shorter. Try expanding your fiddle's preview width and it turns back into a column. That's how we can create responsible websites w/ bootstrap. If you want to dig deeper into it, I suggest reading [bootstrap's grid system manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). Instead of `column-md-4` you may use `col-4` and it will be shown as a column independently of your device's width, for example.
2. I recommend reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089115/relative-div-height). The way `height` works in CSS is slightly different than `width`, so what you need is to set a reference on either your `html` or `body` tags.